# I get two different amount for machine epsilon when I use below python codes, what is the reason?

Tags: python

I get two different amount for machine epsilon when I use below python codes, what is the reason?

```
i=1
while i+1 != 1 :
    m=i
    i=i/2
print(m)
```

and

```
i=1
while i != 0 :
    m=i
    i=i/2
print(m)
```

dividing the output of the first code by 2 is not equal to zero, but dividing output of the second code by 2 is zero!

Comment: You are assuming `i + 1` is exact; that's not true for numbers very close to 0, because adding one "steals" a bit of precision away from the fractional part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Searching in python documentation I found [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.float_info).
Python shows 16 digits of a float number, if it is more than 16 digits python rounds it. It doesn't mean the minimum number that can be represented by python is 10^-16. It can represent 0.00000000000000000001234567887654321 but not 1.12345678876543211

Answer (score 2):

If you add a count to each loop you'll see that the second iterates *a lot* more times than the first

```
i=1
count = 0
while i+1 != 1 :
    count += 1
    m=i
    i=i/2

print(count)
```

> 53

```
i=1
count = 0
while i != 0 :
    count += 1
    m=i
    i=i/2

print(count)
```

> 1075

The reason for this is floating point maths, and you shouldn't try to explicitly check a floating point number for equality with another. See [What is the best way to compare floats for almost-equality in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595425/what-is-the-best-way-to-compare-floats-for-almost-equality-in-python) for a possible solution, and [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) for more information on floats.

Comment: Note: Number of iterations may differ

Comment: Thank you dear Sayse. Actually I'm seeking for machine epsilon and I think in this case defining tolerance is meaningless. What is your idea?